# Using array_diff for broad matches?

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

What I'm trying to do is take items from one array, such as:

```
$array1 = array(
"google-com",
"youtube-com",
);
```

And remove items from a second array if the above items are included (but BROAD match, not exact).

```
$array2 = array(
"www-google-com",
"www-youtube-com",
"www-facebook-com",
"www-twitter-com",
);
```

Expected output:

```
 www-facebook-com
 www-twitter-com
```

Note: The first array would be with "example.com" style URLs and the second with "https://www.example.com/" URLs.

It seems array_diff only works with exact matches, and after much searching, I can't seem to find a way to make it work for broad matches.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you not able to better prepare one of the arrays?  Is this sample data realistic data in terms of your project? <- this matters

Comment: The idea is to save time, hence why the arrays are in different formats. I'm reviewing the various responses now. Thanks everyone for your time!

Comment: In the future, Joe, please always complete your question by providing your best failing coding attempt.  This is a sign of respect toward volunteers among other things.

Comment: Not my DV, just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `array_diff` is not a solution here. One of the solutions is using a `preg_grep` to find records and then unset keys in `$array2`:

```
$array1 = array(
    "google-com",
    "youtube-com",
);

$array2 = array(
    "www-google-com",
    "www-youtube-com",
    "www-facebook-com",
    "www-twitter-com",
);

foreach ($array1 as $search) {
    foreach (preg_grep('/' . $search . '/', $array2) as $index => $value) {
        unset($array2[$index]);
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

Comment: `preg_quote()` may be necessary in the project, but not in the sample data.  I don't think I like the iterated `preg_` calls.

Comment: Several of the answers here work beautifully.  This has a shorter syntax but may be prone to breakage depending on your actual project input and is possibly the slowest performer.  FYI @Joe

Comment: Actually your response @mickmackusa does seem to be more 'polished' in the sense that it resets the keys as well, and makes the new first key "0". If I end up using your answer I will change the correct answer selection on this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to iterate over each of the arrays, using a function such as `strpos` to see if the short URLs are contained in the longer ones:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array2 as $url) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($array1 as $short_url) {
        $found = $found || (strpos($url, $short_url) !== false);
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $output[] = $url;
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => www-facebook-com
    [1] => www-twitter-com
)
```

Without knowing exactly what you mean by a `BROAD` match, `strpos` is probably close. You can always write a custom function to do the matching and replace `strpos` in the code above with it.

Answer (score 2):

When making iterated searches, always provide an early exit.

Nested loops with early `break` conditions will be most performant.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tJejj))

```
$array1 = array(
"google-com",
"youtube-com",
);

$array2 = array(
"www-google-com",
"www-youtube-com",
"www-facebook-com",
"www-twitter-com",
);

foreach ($array2 as $index => $haystack) {
    foreach ($array1 as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            unset($array2[$index]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($array2));
```

That said, if your data is somewhat predictable and you can prepare just one of the arrays, you can spare much of this iterated work.

Comment: There is no risk when iterating a copy of the data. @viv

Comment: Please avoid seeding fears unless you can provide a case where this breaks.  Foreach is working on a copy of the array by default.  It would be better to inform the OP of the performance gains and stability of this answer.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: The most performant way I feel(though seems like an overkill if the dataset is small) is to make a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of `$array1` in a reversed word way and to search through $array2's each site in a reversed word way in the trie.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)

```
$array1 = array(
"google-com",
"youtube-com",
);
$array1 = preg_filter('/^/', 'www-', $array1);

$array2 = array(
"www-google-com",
"www-youtube-com",
"www-facebook-com",
"www-twitter-com",
);


print_r(array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

Comment: "Hope this helps" is not an explanation of how your solution work nor why you believe the technique is advisable.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't account for the many possible variations of a URL. For example, if the URL is http or https and also the trailing slash on the end. It's a very narrow response, but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: If your posted sample data doesn't effectively reflect the the quality and variability of your project data, then the onus is on your sample data, not this volunteer's solution.  You must provide realistic data if you expect to receive the best / most durable solutions. @Joe